# Getting a TypeError for constructor when mocking my database class

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a simple query which uses a database wrapped in a class below. When I write the jest test I get a faiure about the database class not being a constructor. I have placed the details in code here,

```js
                   export class ProductDb {

                    findProductById = async (productId: string) => {
                        return await ProductModel.find({ _id: productId })
                    }
                  }

                    export class ProductService {
  
                      private  db:ProductDb
   
                       constructor(){
                         this.db = new ProductDb()
                      }
                   }
     
                    processProduct = async(productId:string): Promise<any> =>{
                    const product = await this.db.findProductById(productId).then
                    /// rest of processing
                  }
  
               }
```

When I mock the database I get an error saying it is not a constructor:

```
TypeError: productDb_1.ProductDb is not a constructor
```

Here is the core piece of the test where I set up the mock for ProductDb

```js
          const findProductByIdMock = jest.fn()

          jest.mock('../product/database/ProductDb', () =>{
           
           return {
             
               ProductDb: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
               
               return {
                  findProductById: findProductByIdMock
                 }
               })
               }
           })

           describe('Product test suite', () =>{
               
               beforeEach(() =>{
                   jest.clearAllMocks()
               }
               
               it('should product with prices', async() =>{
                  const product = {
                     name: ''bananas
                  }
                  findProductByIdMock.mockResolvedValueOnce(product)
                  // rest of test
               }
           
           }
```

I really have no idea why I am getting this error and i have spent days trying to figure out what's going on. I would appreciate some hep in solving this issue

Comment: what bundler are you using?

Comment: I am working on the server side with Node JS. I am not using a bundler

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: I use node's package manager, i.e. npm test

Comment: @BreenDeen npm is not a test runner, and Jest can't directly use Typescript files. When you type "npm test" in the shell and hit enter, what command actually runs? What is "test" mapped to in the scripts section of your package.json? Are you using ts-jest, or babel, or what?

Comment: Jest is the test runner, but I run it using npm test which is configured to use Jest in jestconfig.ts and in package.jsom

Answer (score 0):

According the official docs, to do a manual mock it should be:

> ```
> import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';
> const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();
> jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
>   return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
>     return {playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile};
>   });
> });
> ```

So the correct syntax in your case should be:

```js
jest.mock("../product/database/ProductDb", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        findProductById: jest.fn(),
      };
  });
});
```

Comment: The code I provided works. I noticed that when I use several of those mocks of different classes, then it becomes a problem.. I have other repositories for different classes ProductDB, OrderDB etc. When I define mocks for those in the same file that's when I encounter the problem. If I comment out the others it works